# How to cast json object into a string

Tags: c#

Here i'm having json string and i wanted to get one perticular key and value from this json string.So I have used javascript serializer for that.
Below is the code which i have used in C#.Net.

```
string strProfile = fbApi.GetForStr("/statefarm/feed/");
var jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
var dictionary = (IDictionary<string, object>)jss.DeserializeObject(strProfile);  
object keyvalue = (object)dictionary["paging"]; 
string data = keyvalue.ToString();
```

When i do this  I'm not able to fetch the keyvale pair from the jsonstring. If i write

```
string keyvalue = (string)dictionary["paging"];
```

instead of

```
object keyvalue = (object)dictionary["paging"]; 
string data = keyvalue.ToString();
```

getting on exception called

> object of type 'system.object ' to type 'system.string '

What to do for this and how it can bne written.

Comment: well ... its type is `System.Object` - what do you expect? that the cast works ootb?! ... nope ... `.ToString()` or any other conversion will be your friend!

Comment: Have you tried dictionary["paging"].toString() or something similar?

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that you are using the Facebook API using some SDK / your custom code here. [JSON.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/projects/json-net.aspx) is the best way to go unless you don't want to end up in the unholy mess of Key Value paired JSON.

Try this.

```
var api = new FacebookClient
{
    AccessToken = accessToken,
    AppId = AppID,
    AppSecret = AppSecret
};
dynamic result = api.Get("me/posts");
string JsonConvert.SerializeObject(result, new KeyValuePairConverter())
```

or to avoid confusion, simply add this to your code

```
object keyvalue = (object)dictionary["paging"];
JsonConvert.SerializeObject(keyvalue , new KeyValuePairConverter());
```

The *NewtonSoft.Json.dll* is also available as a Nuget package.

Comment: Yes naveen here i'm using facebook api's to download the data which is in json format which s working fine .But i want to get one key-valu pair from the json string which is not working fine.

Comment: Also  object keyvalue = (object)dictionary["paging"]; Here in keyvalue getting that key-vale pair as an object .But if i want to store as a string its throwing me an error.